# How to get sensor_msgs dependency with catkin (fuerte)

Tags: catkin, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After upgrading to fuerte, the ros command "rospack depends sensor_msgs" is empty.

I have seen, that in fuerte some packages have changed the buildchain to catkin.

But how is it possible to get the dependency of this package with catkin? For example it depends of "geometry_msgs".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33783/how-to-get-sensor_msgs-dependency-with-catkin-(fuerte)/) by [Puto_77](https://answers.ros.org/users/2366/puto_77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-11**:
This happens on Oneiric, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug that should be fixed in upcoming Debian packages. See [this](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3956) ticket.

**Edit**: Fixed in current Debian packages.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-11**:
The patched version of common_msgs has been released.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Interesting question. I observed the same behavior for ROS fuerte installed with apt-get. For a source-compiled ROS fuerte, rosdep still behaves as in earlier versions, i.e.:

name@machine$ rospack depends sensor_msgs

geometry_msgs

---

Originally posted by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) with karma: 290 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1